# How to display color picker in MVC razor view

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a project created using MVC 5 , the views are created based on html razor a,Javascript and Jquery .

one of my views that is used to insert data , contains a textbox which i want it to display color picker if user click on it .

I tried to use this library jscolor.js ,  but it works in pure HTML page and i failed to make it work in Razor view , i don't know why .

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>jscolor Example</title>
</head>
<body style="text-align:center;">
    <script src="jscolor.js"></script>
    <h2>Example 1</h2>
    Color: <input class="jscolor" value="ab2567">
</body>
</html>
```

the link for Javascript library http://jscolor.com/

and here is the code in the MVC view

```
<script src="jscolor.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        jscolor.installByClassName("jscolor");
    });
</script>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Create, "DateField", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <input class="jscolor" value="ab2567"/>
....etc
```

anybody have information about this ??

Comment: What razor code have you tried?

Comment: @Html.TexBoxFor(m=>m.color, new{@class="jscolor"})

Comment: So what problems are you having?

Comment: I tried the code above inside an html page and it works fine , the i copied it into an MVC view ,, exactly as it is , i mean i embedded the Jscolor.js file on the top of the page then in @BeginForm i set an input and tried to run this but it doesn't display the color picker

Comment: Not related but delete the `min` version (you should not have 2 copies)

Comment: i deleted it and it doesn't work

Comment: That why I said _Not related but_ :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129133/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-laila).

Answer (score 3):

Try Below code. It worked for me.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PropertyList.color, new { @class = "jscolor"})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add an  using the following syntax too

```
@Html.TextBoxFor((m => m.PropertyList.color, new { type="color"})
```